# Using one click install after first install in electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Is there a way that the same `electron-builder` installer can first check if the app is already installed. If it is, use the one click install option, otherwise use the complete installer?

In electron builder we have the option to build a one click installer or a more standard installer. Currently, we always use the standard installer as we prefer allowing user to decide where to install our app and whether to install for all users or not. Once this is done, for updates, we like the option for the user to "reinstall" the latest software. For this purpose the `one click` install option makes more sense.

Note: I couldn't find this question asked anywhere but seems like a common question to me. If duplicate, please post link here and I will remove question.

Answer (score 1):

The standard installer lets the user decide to install the app on a per machine or per user basis, while the one click installer will only install the software on a per machine basis.

So you have a potential problem:

If the initial install is done on a per machine basis, the one click installer will work without a problem.  However, if the initial install is done on a per user basis, the subsequent quick installer will try to install itself across the machine, which will result in an install error.

So you should either only ship one type of installer, or both.